# Public SQLite Database for android users

Tags: android, database, sqlite

If I create an android database using SQLite it will be local, just for the phone in which the database is stored?

And how can I create a database which could be used and updated from different phones? For example, I have database with friends online and if someone turns on the program then it stores an entry in table which is seen by all of the users friends?

Maybe, some tutorials on creating remote database (if included database is not public).
I searched google, but the only thing I found was simple database tutorials, which, as I suppose, are stored in phones memory and that means accessable by just that particular phone.

Thank You in advance,
Daniels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to have a remote database that multiple people could connect to you would have to set up something like MySQL or similar. At that point, you would have to set up some sort of API that you could connect through, then you have to worry about access control as well.

The most common one I see around is a PHP frontend so that the entire database connection runs over HTTP example here : [PHP API](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

Comment: PHP file must be placed in remote server too? And this looks like quite easy to use variant, so thank you :)

Comment: Yep, or at least, that's the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a way to do what you asked. You can create a web service that will communicate with your local database and store the data of your local db in an online db using synchronization. The online db doesnt need to be in SQLite.